# json different format

Tags: php, json, format

I have a query:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT
    Left(Right(Base.inputs.Data_inf,4),3) As 'Datas',
    count(Base.Data.Data_ID) As `U_Count`
    FROM
        Base.Data
    WHERE
        Base.Data_inputs.info = 'TREE'
    GROUP BY ");

    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row[0] = $r[0];
        $row[1] = $r[1];
        array_push($rows,$row);
    }

    print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

and the result is:

```
[["Data1",38],["Data2",13]]
```

I would like the data look more like:

```
[{"name":"Data1","data":[38]},{"name":"Data2","data":[13]}]
```

I was trying to use something like this:

```
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
       $rows['name'] = $r['Datas'];
       while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
        $rows['data'][] = $r['U_Count'];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?
THNKS

Comment: If the second value is always going to be a single datum, why do you want to store it as an array?

Comment: Maybe I do not have to, I am a rookie in mysql/php. But I need the output in this format, so I can display it in a column chart. Anyway thnks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the data and store it as an array.

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
   $rows[] = array('name'=>$r['Datas'],'data'=>array($r['U_Count']));
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it works, thnks a lot, now I have to get through the code, co I can understand it :) Thnks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_object()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    ...
```